# Tmux and term-mode

Tags: ansi-term, term, multi-term

I've been running tmux inside of my `term` buffer but when I do that there are some issues and the buffer often becomes messed up, with the cursor being in the wrong spot and overwriting text or other various small issues. These issues arise from scrolling, typing the clear command or a variety of other inputs.

Has anybody been able to find a way around this? A way to have tmux play nicely with term mode?

The end goal is to have persistent shells that I can interact with within emacs and that will last even after I inevitably crash emacs. Any way to do this would be greatly appreciated, I was simply trying with tmux.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the value of `echo $TERM`? I use `eterm-color` and `tmux` just works inside `term`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22091145/1937596